# Unable to click a link in a table

Tags: selenium, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my code (in Python):

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Documents/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://comprasnet.gov.br/acesso.asp?url=/livre/Pregao/ata0.asp')

#FIRST PAGE
driver.switch_to.frame('main2')
driver.find_element_by_name('dt_ini_sessao').send_keys('18/04/2018')
driver.find_element_by_name('dt_fim_sessao').send_keys('18/04/2018')
driver.find_element_by_name('ok').click()
```

Until here it is fine, code is running smoothly. However when I get to the second page I'm not able to click the link I want.

```
#SECOND PAGE
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/a').click()
```

[image]

Can someone help?

Comment: Why do you want to click on that link in particular? Is it based on the number, code, name or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate through all the links from the first table row on second page you can use below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Documents/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://comprasnet.gov.br/acesso.asp?url=/livre/Pregao/ata0.asp')

#FIRST PAGE
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_name("main2")))
driver.find_element_by_name('dt_ini_sessao').send_keys('18/04/2018')
driver.find_element_by_name('dt_fim_sessao').send_keys('18/04/2018')
driver.find_element_by_name('ok').click()

#SECOND PAGE
links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//td[1]/a")))]

for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    # Do something on each page
```

or

```
#SECOND PAGE
links_count = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//td[1]/a"))))

for index in range(links_count):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//td[1]/a")))[index].click()
    # Do something on each page
    driver.get('http://comprasnet.gov.br/acesso.asp?url=/livre/Pregao/ata0.asp')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_name("main2")))
    driver.find_element_by_name('dt_ini_sessao').send_keys('18/04/2018')
    driver.find_element_by_name('dt_fim_sessao').send_keys('18/04/2018')
    driver.find_element_by_name('ok').click()
```

Comment: Is there a way to use click instead of get? That's because if I click it goes to a different page than using get.

Comment: great suggestion, thanks, now I'm able to click it. In the third page I'm using WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//td/input[4]")))[index].click(), the driver.back works fine but when I get back it doesn't keep iterating among links. Do you know what that could be?

Comment: It's a single-page site and it seem that clicking Back in Browser doesn't lead to the same (SECOND) page. You need to add more lines in loop

Answer (score 1):

you can use `find_elements_by_tag_name` instead . It will give you fill list of  tag `a` that has the .click method.

Following is the working code example.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://comprasnet.gov.br/acesso.asp?url=/livre/Pregao/ata0.asp')

#FIRST PAGE
driver.switch_to.frame('main2')
driver.find_element_by_name('dt_ini_sessao').send_keys('18/04/2018')
driver.find_element_by_name('dt_fim_sessao').send_keys('18/04/2018')
driver.find_element_by_name('ok').click()
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a') :
    if elem.text == "3112017" :
        elem.click()
```

Comment: thanks @toheedNiaz. Later on I will want to iterate among all the links in the table. Following your suggestion I would be restricted to "3112017". Would you have a more flexible suggestion?

Comment: @abutremutante, can you update your question with this additional requirement?